# Book manager app with PDF update option

Tags: ipad, books

Backstory: I bought a book from a third-party publisher and uploaded it on Apple Books just to find out that I cannot update the book (PDF), the issue is that I had all my notes and scribbles on the first upload and cannot migrate it on the updated version.

**Is there an ebook app on iPad where I can update PDF/Epub/Mobi without losing my scribbles and writen notes?**

Comment: How do you expect it to work? If the updated pdf adds a page at the beginning - how do your scribbles chnage? I can't see how this could be implemented

Comment: @mmmmmm please reread what I wrote, I want the PDF/Epub/Mobi to update the source file and not everything that's on top

Comment: That would do exactly what mmmmmm said. The two would be disassociated & no longer in sync. If you'd annotated the third word on page 42, how would this association be maintained if the underlying document changes?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, the association and the location of any form of modifications will be maintained, the location will be saved based on the page, if there is additional page added then there will be a shift of notes and scribbles, which for my case will be fine.

Comment: That would require the update doing a diff on the two files to see if it could figure out what had been moved to where. That aside, software recommendations really belong on the relatively new https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ They usually get closed on here.

Comment: I am guessing the closes thing I can do is slice and stick with a pdf manager app

Comment: To add to the complexity of things, there could also be annotated words in version 1 which are deleted/replaced in version 2. LiquidText [seems to offer something like this](https://twitter.com/LiquidTextCorp/status/1502098732883402752?s=20&t=Gcb77cN8WFdSVX2ZJ6rPaw) but only if you used the app for the initial set of annotations.